# JBoss Fuse 6.3, Maven and settings.xml

Tags: maven, jbossfuse

I'm trying to follow [Red Hat JBoss Fuse-6.3 Developer Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/pdf/developing_and_deploying_applications/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse-6.3-Developing_and_Deploying_Applications-en-US.pdf).  I added everything to the `Windows: Documents and Settings\User\.m2\settings.xml` (which didnt exist) as per the document.
The build command I'm using is
`C:\Apps\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=io.fabric8.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=karaf-soap-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.2.0.redhat-630187 -DgroupId=org.fusesource.example -DartifactId=cxf-basic -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dfabric8-profile=cxf-basic-profile`

I'm now getting this error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[INFO] Archetype repository not defined. Using the one from [io.fabric8.archetypes:karaf-soap-archetype:1.2.0.redhat-133] found in catalog remote
[WARNING] The POM for io.fabric8.archetypes:karaf-soap-archetype:jar:1.2.0.redhat-630187 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.056 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-17T10:31:19-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/54M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (io.fabric8.archetypes:karaf-soap-archetype:1.2.0.redhat-630187) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

C:\P\Projects\JBoss_Dev_Studio-10.1.0.GA_SideProjects\get-started>
```

I do see that [archetype](https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/io/fabric8/archetypes/karaf-soap-archetype/1.2.0.redhat-630187/) exists.

Googling around for `archetype does not exist (io.fabric8.archetypes:karaf-soap-archetype:1.2.0.redhat-630187` and yes!  It's one of those 0 results found!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key turned out to be this

`[INFO] Archetype repository not defined. Using the one from [io.fabric8.archetypes:karaf-soap-archetype:1.2.0.redhat-133] found in catalog remote`

`[WARNING] The POM for io.fabric8.archetypes:karaf-soap-archetype:jar:1.2.0.redhat-630187 is missing, no dependency information available`

And me being a bit of a newb with Maven - I didnt understand it first.  I then googled a bit more for settings.xml - I then found mention of a settings.xml also contained in `C:\Apps\apache-maven-3.5.0\conf`

I added the Red Hat repositories to that file instead (as it was completely empty) and everything now builds properly.  Hopefully this might help someone else figure out a similar problem faster than I did whether it's with regards to jboss fuse or maven not being correctly setup,